# Printing statement in c

Tags: c, printf

What if we just give format string in printf statement in c like:

```
printf("%d, %d, %d",a, b);
```

What does the third `%d` give In answer?

I did it but not able to understand the output of the code.

Comment: It will give undefined behavior, and you certainly should not do this unless you are trying to break something.

Comment: it's worth highlighting that "UB" means that it might not actually print anything at all ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third %d gives in answer undefined behavior because there is no corresponding argument.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.275) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Pay attention to that the name of the standard function is `printf` not `Printf`.

Answer (score 0):

In C, functions that take variadic arguments (i.e. the `...` parameter) have no way of knowing beforehand the number or type of the arguments. They must be kept track of in some way. A separate length parameter is one way, but the `printf`-family functions use the number of format specifiers in the format string to keep track.

If you tell the function "hey, there's a third parameter" when you don't pass one, this is undefined behavior. Anything can happen. It may appear to not print anything. It may read a garbage value from the memory location or the register where it expects to find the value. It may crash.

Reasoning about what might happen when your code invokes undefined behavior is a waste of time. Just make sure your code is free of it.

Answer (score 0):

You've told `printf` to expect 3 additional `int` arguments, but only passed 2.  It's going to look for that third `int` argument *somewhere*, and depending on how `printf` is implemented on your system, you may get a runtime error, or you may see garbage output, or you may see *no* output, or something entirely different may happen.

Officially, the behavior is left *undefined* - neither the compiler nor the runtime environment the program is executing in are required to handle the situation in any particular way.  The result isn't guaranteed to be predictable or repeatable.

There is no "should" here - *any* result is "correct" as far as the language definition is concerned.